# Chrome Refresh "resubmit form data" Submits Null

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, post

As stated, In VS2017 my asp.net mvc application submits a null value when refreshing and "resubmitting" (for a built in search) in chrome only. All other browsers work normally. Google search has yielded nothing useful. I'm not sure where to begin.

Additionally, as this might be related - I've at the same time had to disable chrome javascript debugging in visual studio settings as VS will freeze with JS debugging enabled.

This issue applies to Version 60.0.3112.101 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google seems to know about this issue, they have a bug ticket opened at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=747812.

Doesn't help us right now, but good to know that it's not an issue with our code!

Comment: 1 year later the bug still remains... I didn't notice this issue few month ago.